# WRT54GL firmware extraction via JTAG with OpenOCD and Raspberry Pi as interface. Can not dump because the device is not halted

Tags: mips, jtag

Good day!

Sorry to come up with something very old. Since I am currently teaching myself hardware hacking, I wanted to use my old router for this. I soldered pins to the JTAG interface and connected them to my Pi2 GPIO. I connected them as follows:
[image]
Unfortunately, I cannot dump the firmware because the device does not want to switch to halt. Only time-out for halt request appears.

I have changed the freq, checked for cold solder joints. (I don't have any errors)

```
init
reset halt
JTAG tap: bcm5352e.cpu tap/device found: 0x0535217f (mfg: 0x0bf, part:
0x5352, ver: 0x0)
Halt timed out, wake up GDB.
timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: bcm5352e.cpu - Not halted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be about RE as such. Looks like your target is not fully supported by OpenOCD. I suggest you to use their support channels to make ‘reset halt’ work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for electronics.stackexchange.com